# How to solve cros policy problem in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I don't understand why `https://example.com/id` is not blocked by CROS policy while `https://example.com/id/` is blocked in my Laravel 9 project

Here is my CROS config.php file

```
 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: We need more information here: (a) Have you set the cors middleware in your global middleware stack? (b) why do you not have `id` in your `paths` entry? (c) can you show us your route definition ? (d) can you share the exact CORS error your are seeing ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Middleware and put this line in it:

```
        $response = $next($request);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Token-Auth,Authorization');

    return $response;
```

and your problem will be solved

You Can check [this repo](https://github.com/somarkn99/api-basic-setting) for more details